# Validate Radio selection using Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to return false if no radio button has been selected using the following script:

```
function validatefilling(){
    var a=document.getElementById("myfilling");
    if (fillingselected == 0){
        var resultloc=document.getElementById("fillingerror");
        resultloc.innerHTML =  "<span style='color:red;'>Please select a filling!<span>";
        return false;
    }
    var resultloc=document.getElementById("fillingerror");
    resultloc.innerHTML =  "";
    return true;
}
```

It doesn't seem to work however.  I am trying to have the message "Please select a filling!" appear if nothing has been selected after the user submits the form. "fillingselected" is the value of the radio form submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(!document.getElementById('myfilling').checked) {
    var resultloc=document.getElementById("fillingerror");
    resultloc.innerHTML =  "<span style='color:red;'>Please select a filling!<span>";
    return false;
} else {
    var resultloc=document.getElementById("fillingerror");
    resultloc.innerHTML =  "";
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The OP did not indicate that he is using jQuery.

Comment: @steve are you happy now?

Comment: hmm the error message appears onsubmit but when I select a value it returns the error message again

Comment: @Jeb please check my updated answer it won't show you the error message if you select radio button now.

Comment: so strange.  I think your code is correct but I keep getting the error message onsubmit. Do you think something else could be wrong with my code?

Comment: Am I supposed to be setting the ID of each radio selection to "myfilling"? That's what I currently have...